# Rails - Will I lose my development database when I push to production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, development-environment, production-environment

I know this is probably dumb question but...

Simply put, I have an app with a database of hundreds of records in development mode. When I push to production and deploy onto the internet, will I lose my database and have to redo it all in production mode?

Just being safe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your production database is not pushed. An empty database with your schemas will be created when you run rake exec db:migrate on your production server.

If you want to automate adding your development database records to your production database, there is a gem called yaml_db. It is easy to use and works on MySQL and PostgreSQl. https://github.com/yamldb/yaml_db.

In gemfile:

```
gem 'yaml_db'
```

Then, in your console

```
$ bundle install
```

```
rake db:data:dump   ->   Dump contents of Rails database to db/data.yml
rake db:data:load   ->   Load contents of db/data.yml into the database
```

Take a look at the spec for all details.

**EDITED: Addition**

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake db:data:dump
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:data:load
```

Comment: so would i be a good idea to deply my website first, and then add my database records to the production database? or is it better to transfer development db to production via the yaml_db gem?

also, if I transfer, will there be any risk of losing data?

Comment: Yes. Deploy first. Rake everything that needs to be raked and make sure your app is successfully deployed and running. There will be no data but everything should work.. Then, use the yaml_db gem to copy files to a yaml dump file. Your source database (development) will not be modified, but if it makes you feel more comfortable by all means make a backup before you start the process.

Comment: I think I understand why you asked the question above. This may be a subtle point, but important -- you dump the file in your development environment and load the file in the production environment. The gem is good, but the process is not uncomplicated. I used it because I had a lot of development tables with data that I didn't want to have to re-enter in production.

Comment: Added explicit instructions for yaml_db use in the answer.

Comment: wow! thanks valerie! really helpful and cleared up my confusion :)

Comment: one last question, if I decide to make changes to my website (mainly front end changes), will I have to re-rake the database?

Answer (score 2):

Sort of, you won't lose the data itself, that's stored in a database you configured for the development environment, but your production environment likely will have configured another database, which will be empty.

You could copy the database from the development environment and configure rails to use that in production. Depends a bit on what kind of database you use: mysql, sqlite, etc.

Comment: so I can just copy the development database to be used in production? will there be any loss of data or performance issues?

Comment: Yes, in case of mysql you export and reimport it. On the server you probably need to tune mysql.conf a bit for optimal performance.